# ASP.NET Dynamic Menu is not showing submenu in touch Devices

Tags: asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap, css, mobile

**ASP.NET dynamically generated Menu is not showing sub menu  in touch devices like android mobile**

In desktop application sub menu appear on mouse over automatically but on touch devices it show only first level of menu.

I tried `Selectable = true;` but it also not working.

You can see live demo at [Sanisoft-it.com/faq.aspx](http://sanisoft-it.com/faq.aspx)
If you are using desktop then make your browser Responsive Design mode

Comment: There is no `hover` event on touch devices

Comment: yes @Morpheus but what will be the alternative solution for this problem.

Comment: Alternative is `touchstart` and `touchend` events. Note that these are javascript events and you can't control them in CSS

Comment: Is it possible that I can apply that events on .net code? like I'm creating menu through c# back end coding.

Comment: No, as I mentioned these are javascript events; not sure if you can do in C#